# change startOnTick after a (High)chart has been created

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I set the Y axis ranging from 110 to 210? The following code does not work (the Y axis shows values from 100 to 250):

```
 $(function () {
    var chart= new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo:'container'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
    chart.yAxis[0].startOnTick=true;
    chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(110, 210);
    });
```

Notice that I need to modify axis parameters after the chart has been created. jfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc4bw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
yAxis: {
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false
        }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bc4bw/10/

Answer (score 0):

You can also set min/max values for yAxis.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max